# WordPress: Get $table_prefix for own plugin function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin to access own tables in the WP database that use the `$table_prefix` of `wp-config.php`. How can I refer to this variable from a function in my plugin code?

I'm a WordPress and PHP beginner, so it might be very trivial. Still Google couldn't really help me with this. The most promising solution I found didn't work:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->table_prefix;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the wrong name. It's `$wpdb->prefix`: [$wpdb class - Properties](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#properties).

```
global $wpdb;

$my_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_table';
var_dump( $my_table_name );
```

Comment: Worked fine to me, thanks